# Porcelain - stop function does not kill the process

Tags: elixir

I use Porcelain with goon_linux_amd64 driver on debian. 
I run the long-running ffmpeg process with the following command:

```
new_process = Porcelain.spawn("ffmpeg", ["options", "here"])
```

Then i killed the process:

```
Porcelain.Process.stop(new_process)
```

and finally:

```
Porcelain.Process.alive?(new_process)
false
```

The problem is that the process is not actually killed. I can see it when I exec the ps aux command.

Comment: Known issue? https://github.com/alco/porcelain/issues/39

Answer (score 0):

Main idea of Porcelain and Elixir/Erlang `Port` module is to handle outside processes using stdin and stdout channels. And when you call `stop(pid)` you terminate internal process and stdin/stdout channels (but not external OS process).

Issue is that not all programs are actually terminates in case of closing stdin/stdout.
Solution in most cases is to wrap your external process into wrapper: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Port.html#module-zombie-os-processes

Same issue with Porcelain.